# Retry connection according to condition Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an awkward problem that I'm really confused on the least worse way to solve it.

The problem is, I have 2 activities, one displaying a list and a "New" button. When I click this new button the user goes to the creation screen, upload a photo, input some info and send. Once this process succeeds, the user is moved back to the previous activity, the list gets refreshed and the new item is displayed.
But in the backend the image is processed in AWS Lambda, meaning that when the list refresh occurs, the newly added image is never show, so the user needs to leave and get back to the screen (of course, it's horrible).

My question is, what is the best way to "pull" the server to get this image ??
I'm using Retrofit.

Some code:

```
    KidsService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(KidsService.class, BuildConfig.API_URL, DindaApplication.getSessionRepository().getSession());

            service.getKids(new Callback<KidsList>() {
                @Override
                public void success(KidsList kidsList, Response response) {
                    mView.onFetchKids(kidsList);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    mView.onFetchKidsError(error);
                }
            });

 @Override
    public void onFetchKids(KidsList kids) {
        loadKids(kids);
    }
private void loadKids(KidsList kids) {
        hideLoading();

        if (kids != null && kids.getKids().size() > 0) {
            mKids = kids;

            if (mAdapter == null) {
                mAdapter = new KidsAdapter();
                mAdapter.setListener(this);
            }

            mAdapter.setKidsList(mKids);
            mKidsRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mKidsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            if (mConfirmationMsg != null){
                Snackbar.make(getView(), mConfirmationMsg, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            showMessage();
        }
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: Its very simple, just keep a copy of the image on upload in your app private or sdcard directory for temp use, and use it on Activity navigation.

Comment: The problem is the image belong to a list (like a friend list) with photo and name. I'd need to iterate through the list to find the newly created id and manually set the photo. Is this the best approach ?

Comment: why are you generating new ids? If items in the list are populated from a dataset then there should a Unique id in dataset, set name of each image by some convention and use it.